# Datagridview pop up

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am new to VB and .NET, and I am trying to display a message box when the user double clicks on a data grid, to display selected data.

Normally I can just use `MessageBox("Hello")` from windows control with the button click event.

But when I type MessageBox("Hello") from datagridview's double click event, I get a compile error

> 'MessageBox' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.

I also tried to create a second blank form on visual studio, on button click event I typed in: `Form2.Show()`, and I did the same on datagridview double click event.
When I click the button Form2 is displayed but when I double click on datagridview, Form2 is not displayed.

Any reason why datagridview control behave differently than other windows control?, and what is the best and easy way to display pop-up windows or display 2nd form when user double click on datagridview?

What I am trying to do is when the user double clicks on datagridview, I would like to create a pop-up form, and fill in some of the data from selected datagridview row on the pop-up form.

---

I am not sure how to reply to Alex suggestion, I try to add comment but it says more than 125 characters and I could not find button to reply the thread, so I just put it here. (let me know if there is better way to do this instead of keep adding to my questions).

Hi Alex,

this is the code that I have on form1 class, form2 class is just a simple blank form, I just create add new form right click add form from Visual Studio.
After I click the button form2 is pop up then I close it Form2, then double click datagridview cell, nothing happen, the I click the button form2 is pop up.

Thank you.

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TestDB1DataSet.t_emp' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.T_empTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDB1DataSet.t_emp)

```
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    ' put some code here
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Can you post some example of what are you doing?

Comment: `MessageBox` *is* is a type. Use the `.Show()` method: `MessageBox.Show(...)`

Comment: Use `MsgBox("Hello")` instead

Comment: A VERY late reply and it's probably too late... but I couldn't understand what you said in that edit - is the problem solved or is it still persisting? I don't imagine it matters though.

Answer (score 1):

These are very easy to make mistakes:

1. The `MessageBox("Hello")` should be `MessageBox.Show("Hello")` - as simple as that. `MessageBox` is a type; `Show` is the method that you call.
2. The reason, I believe, the double click event on the datagridview did not work is because you need to check if they are clicking on the cells *as well as* checking if they double click on the grey area of it (which is what the double click method does!) So use this code here - be sure to replace 'Datagridview1' in the part after where it says `Handles` to whatever the name of the `DataGridView` is:

   ```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDoubleClick
       DoubleClickDataGrid()
   End Sub

   Private Sub TYPEANYNAMEHERE(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick
   DoubleClickDataGrid()
   End Sub

   Sub DoubleClickDataGrid()
       ' Type the code here
   End Sub
   ```

Whatever code you want it to do when you double click will go where it says 'Type the code here'

(For Example: `Form2.Show` or `MessageBox.Show("Hello"))` etc.

Comment: You mention in your answer that OP should use `MessageBox.Show`, but your code uses `MsgBox`; please either be consistent or explain what `MsgBox`is and why you use it.

Comment: I am incredibly sorry, that was a mistake - I have edited it now and I will make sure that does not happen again.